# FontAwesome 5 Icons won't Show on Generated PDF using mpdf package in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, mpdf, font-awesome-5

I used composer to install mpdf

`composer require carlos-meneses/laravel-mpdf`

did all the settings in config/app.php file.

The webfonts TTF files copied to  resources/fonts/ folder.
Added this to your configuration file (/config/pdf.php):

```
<?php
return [
    'custom_font_dir' => base_path('resources/fonts/'), // don't forget the trailing slash!
    'custom_font_data' => [
        'examplefont' => [
            'R'  => 'fa-regular-400.ttf',    // regular font
            'B'  => 'fa-solid-900.ttf',       // optional: bold font
        ]
    ]
];
?>
```

used the font in view:

```
.fas {
    font-family: 'examplefont';
}
```

**Versions:**

- PHP: 7.4
- Laravel: 7

but icons not showing in generated pdf. how can I fix this issue?

**Update**

Resolved by [How to use Font Awesome with MPDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432228/how-to-use-font-awesome-with-mpdf)

Comment: `php artisan config:cache` help? Also, I would rather prefer the font files to be in public folder or in storage folder with a shortcut to storage folder made inside public folder. Are you trying to generate PDF on the fly?

Comment: @nice_dev there is no issue in folder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31432228/how-to-use-font-awesome-with-mpdf I used the steps mentioned in this but icon showing in square @arie